# bootstrap selectpicker: Make a select drop down required

Tags: bootstrap-select, laravel-form

I am using bootstrap selectpicker and i want to make a dropdown required. What is the proper way to make a bootstrap selectpicker select required.
(i didn't want's to use any other jquery plugin).

```html
{!! Form::select('from', [], null, ['class' => 'selectpicker form-control', 'data-live-search' => '1', 'data-size' => '6', 'title' => 'Select a partner',]) !!}
```

I am using that selectpicker into laravel form collective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use html5's required

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="txt_kode_supp" required>
</select>
```

for laravel collective:

insert `array('required' => 'required')` into your form collective 3rd parameter